# Function return char[] instead of int

Tags: c, function, pointers

I need some help with my C function.  I'm trying to get the current CPU time and return it as a char[] for use later on.  The problem that I'm getting is that I don't have my pointers/dereferences in the right place and I'm getting compiler warnings/errors.  What changes do I need to make to get this to work correctly?

Function:

```
char *get_time()
{
    char time_char[10];
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;

    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
    int time = timeinfo->tm_yday*1000000 + timeinfo->tm_hour*10000 + timeinfo->tm_min*100 + timeinfo->tm_sec;

    sprintf(time_char, "%d", time);
    return *time_char;
}
```

Calling function with `char time_char[] = get_time();`

What I had before I moved the code to a function and worked as I needed it to was this:

```
char time_char[10];
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;

time ( &rawtime );
timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
int time = timeinfo->tm_yday*1000000 + timeinfo->tm_hour*10000 + timeinfo->tm_min*100 + timeinfo->tm_sec;

sprintf(time_char, "%d", time);
```

And then I used `time_char` as needed.

Comment: Short version - don't. Make function writing to pre-allocated array, like `int get_time(char *out, size_t max_size)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array is allocated in the function's call-frame and is deallocated when the function returns.

You'll either need to pass-in the array by pointer (as keltar comments) in which case you don't need to return anything and the function can be marked `void`, or allocate memory with `malloc` and return the pointer.

Comment: In theory, it could be static variable too. I'm not recommending it, of course - hell of a problems later, and non-existent thread-safety.

Comment: Yes, it seemed like a bad suggestion without a lot more explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Change your prototype to:

```
char *get_time(char *time);
```

Allocate the appropriate memory to `time` in ***the calling function***, then call `free(time);` when you are done using it (also from the calling function).

Also, your return statement should simply be:

```
return time;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't return a pointer to an automatic local variable. Second, to return a pointer you do not need a dereference operator.

Answer (score 0):

Although in general this is not advisable, sometimes it is useful to return a character array, as follows:

```
typedef struct char10 {char str[10];} char10;

char10 get_time() {
    char10 time_char;
    // ...
    sprintf(time_char.str, "%d", time);
    return time_char;
}
```

One downside is that, for example, `gcc` gives an unnecessary warning message for code such as:

```
    printf("%s\n", get_time().str);
```

which you can avoid via the ugly:

```
    printf("%s\n", &get_time().str[0]);
```